# How to resize the exe contained in a panel when the panel is resized (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

With the following code, from my class separated from my MainForm, I create a panel in which I load either another form from my solution or an external exe.

When I load a form and resize the MainForm, the loaded form resizes but if I load an external exe it doesn't resize.

In my external exe I put a button which allows to switch it to Minimized / Maximized and it takes the size of its parent panel.

I would like my imported exe to automatically resize on the resize of the main form.

I am starting and I imagined that I have to get the handle of my exe open in my panel and that in the resize of my main form I do a minimize / maximize of the exe via the handle but I do not know the do or even how and or declare the Handle type variable (a longinit I think).

Maybe there is an easier solution that you can tell me.
If my code is not the best, can you tell me that too because I am learning and want to take best practices.

Thank you for your help.

My Main form code :

```
namespace mtx2
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private static MainForm form1 = null;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form1 = this;
           
        }


        private void iMportToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _UI.ShowPanel(form1, "formtest");

        }

        private void testImportExterForm2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            _UI.ShowPanel(form1, "test.exe");
        }
```

My Class Code :

```
namespace mtx2
{
    public static class _UI
    {
        public static void CachePanels(MainForm frm)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in frm.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is Panel)
                {
                    if (ctrl.Name == "viewer")
                    {
                        ctrl.Dispose();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr Handle, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);

        static readonly int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        static readonly int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        public static void ShowPanel(MainForm frm, string nom)
        {
            CachePanels(frm);

            Panel pnl = new Panel();
            pnl.Name = "viewer";
            pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnl.Visible = true;
            frm.Controls.Add(pnl);

            if (nom.Contains(".exe"))
            {
                Process p = Process.Start(nom);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                p.WaitForInputIdle();
                SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
                MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);
                try
                {
                    foreach (Control ctrl in frm.Controls)
                    {
                        if (ctrl.Name == "viewer")
                        {
                            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, ctrl.Handle);
                            MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, ctrl.Width, ctrl.Height, true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    //
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                formtest myForm = new formtest();
                myForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                myForm.TopLevel = false;
                myForm.AutoScroll = true;
                myForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                foreach (Control ctrl in frm.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl.Name == "viewer")
                    {
                        ctrl.Controls.Add(myForm);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                myForm.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with code formating, sorry but i don't know how to change it

Comment: You main form should have a Resize and also a SizeChanged event. If you add a handler for either of those events, you should then be able to in the event handler grab the reference you have stored for the external exe, and move it / resize it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't know how to do it. I think I need to declare a global variable to store the handle of the opened exe in it, but I don't know how to declare it or how to get it and then I don't know how with the handle we can interact with the exe. Do you have a tutorial or an example please